# fatal: unable to access bitbucket URL: gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

When I am trying to clone the git URL inside my Kubernetes pods. I am getting gnutls handshake issue. Kindly help me, someone to resolve this issue.
Details:
We are using the latest version of Kubernetes with an istio-sidecar gateway.

Comment: Provide the command you are executing.

Comment: git clone https://bitbucketurl/abc.git

Comment: It's defenitely not enough info for troubleshoting. Could you please add to your question exact versions of kubernetes and istio. It could be helpful to know the pod YAML and istio configuration related to this type of traffic. Could you also try to run < curl -v bitbucketurl... > instead of <git clone> and add the output to the question.